# What do you do with settings - make them, adjust them, specify them?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing for an Online Help system and one of the of the requirements is that we try to phrase the headings of topics as tasks when possible and appropriate (e.g. "How to print test pages" instead of naming the topic "Test pages"). A lot of subjects will include a topic on basic settings - which made me wonder: what does the user DO with settings, which verb would be preferable?

To me, the candidates seem to be:

- "Adjust settings": This has the most Google hits and surely sounds best to me,
  but that is mainly based on my gut feeling which might not be the
  most trustworthy source. This is not used in our Online Help so far.
- "Make settings": This is used in our Online Help, but does not sound quite right to me (maybe because I think about the German "machen", which    would not be a good fit). This has a lot of hits on Google, but on    second sight, there are a lot of results from the help systems of    non-american/non-english companies, which at least makes me a bit wary. Other results have "make" in them, but in a slightly different    context (e.g. there's "making settings persistent in GIMP"). But again, my main reason against "make" is my gut feeling.
- "Specify settings": This is also used in our Online Help and to me, it does not sound inherently wrong. Just not right for *basic* settings. This seems more fitting regarding settings that are, well, more *specific*. Third case of gut feeling right here.

So, native speakers out there, what would you prefer? Adjust, make, specify settings, or something else I haven't thought of?

Comment: A bit tautological, perhaps, but you could just ***set*** your settings.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) But, because of it being a bit tautological, to me the heading "How to set the basic settings" would sound a bit like "hey, this guy really wanted to make this heading task-oriented". I guess it would probably be better to just go with "Basic settings" at this point.

Comment: So just say *How to set the basic configuration.* But it is relevant that you're apparently ***not*** including what some might call ***Advanced** Settings?*

Comment: Well, it's not really relevant to the question I guess - it's just the "Basic Settings" part that sounded not quite right to me in combination with "specify", which we have in our help in the context of some advanced/specialised settings. Your solution sounds good - but I think I'll have to stay with "settings" instead of "configuration" because our UI only speaks of "settings". Hmm.

Comment: To me, *adjust settings* is clearly the best. *Make settings* sounds horribly wrong (it sounds like *create settings*), and *specify settings* is just okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Specify settings" - This is OK if the settings don't exist before they are "set".

"Make settings" - *Make* is not quite a substitute for *do* - here, *make* would mean *create*.  Only say this if you literally mean to create a new thing requiring a setting, or if "create new" makes sense in the context.

"Adjust settings" - This is usually OK; there is an arguable implication that you're saying shouldn't have to make major changes.

The action you usually take with settings is *change*, and a good "noun" form of *to change* is either *change* itself or *modification*.

- "Do you want to change setting X?"
- "Would you like to save changes to settings?"
- "Change settings".

Answer (score 0):

*Settings* is a vague concept that will be different for each user and probably change over time while using the tool. It is the concept of having options across multiple parameters. It is not clear if you are referring to the *combination of options* that have been selected for the task, or the *specific location* where options are made.

Refer to the actual *name* of the tool:

> User Preferences, Options Panel

Or the task:

> Printing, Change the ink color, Add a profile photo